# Run docker container on Linux VM which is running on Linux host system

Tags: linux, ssh, docker

My google queries are getting weird because of the architecture:
I am running linux as host and an arch VM as guest. The arch VM does not have a GUI at all, simply the terminal. I mainly access the VM via SSH. The docker containers are currently located on the host system.

I want to run the docker container on the VM. How do I deploy them to the guest system? Is there a golden way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have 2 hosts:
 1. The host you have Docker on;
 2. and the Arch VM on which you do not have Docker.

It does not matter that one is a host for a VM and that the other one is a VM guest. They are 2 different systems.

Now, to answer your question:

To move the Docker containers to another host, you need to turn off those containers first, you **cannot** move them while they are online.

Then, you use `docker commit` to commit and save changes to the container's image. Afterwards, you can just copy the container image over to your VM (via `scp` or any other such means). When you have the container images in your VM, you can just use `docker run` to start them. It's as simple as that.

**However, note that** you do need to install `docker` on your VM in order to do that. As I mentioned, they're two different systems. Virtual machine or not - they do not share anything besides hardware resources.

Comment: Awesome, that was the hint I was looking for! Thank you so much!